Find appropriate rotation matrix
Consider the following elements in linear algebra:
$\pmb{G}: L \times K$ matrix
$\pmb{F}: T \times K$ matrix
$\pmb{H} = \pmb{G} \pmb{F}^{\intercal}: T \times L$ matrix. The apex $\intercal$ denotes the transpose
$\pmb{H}^{OPT}: T \times L$ matrix (notice: $\pmb{H}^{OPT} \neq \pmb{H}$)
It holds that $T > L > K$, and moreover $\pmb{G}$, $\pmb{F}$ have both full rank, so that they have a left-inverse matrix, as pointed out in the comments
My goal is to find a 'map' between $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$ and $\pmb{H}$ so that I can apply a transformation on $\pmb{F}$ and $\pmb{G}$ and obtain a new $\tilde{\pmb{H}} = \tilde{\pmb{G}}\tilde{\pmb{F}}^{\intercal}$ such that it has some properties like $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$.
As suggested in the comments, I to point out what properties to get identification restrictions. In particular, I would like to have that $\tilde{\pmb{H}}$ has the following properties:

each of its column has the same average as each corresponding column of the given $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$
each of its column has the same standard deviation as each corresponding column of the given $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$

I can obtain this with the following two operations:

$\pmb{H}_1 = \pmb{H} * \pmb{\sigma} \pmb{1}^{\intercal} $

where * denotes the Hadamard product, $\pmb{1}$ is a $T \times 1$ vector of ones and $\pmb{\sigma} = (\sigma_{H_{OPT,i}}/\sigma_{H_i}), i=1,2,...L$ is a $L \times 1$ vector where each entry is the ratio of the standard deviation of column $i$ for $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$ and $\pmb{H}$. This expression means that $\pmb{H}_1$ satisfies the second property

$\pmb{H}_2 = \pmb{H}_1 + \pmb{\mu} \pmb{1}^{\intercal} $

where $\pmb{\mu} = (\mu_{H_{OPT,i}} - \mu_{H_{1,i}}), i=1,2,...L$ is a $L \times 1$ vector where each entry is the difference between the mean of column $i$ for $\pmb{H}^{OPT}$ and $\pmb{H}$. This expression means that $\pmb{H}_2$ satisfies the first property and the second property.
Now, I would like to find a transformation to both $\pmb{G}$ and $\pmb{F}$ such that they satisfy the two properties mentioned. The two steps allow me to reach what I want, but in few words, I would like to be able to split them into operations to be applied to both $\pmb{G}$ and $\pmb{F}$.
An approach I had in mind was the use of a rotation matrix. Is it possible to find a rotation matrix $\mathcal{R}$ ($K \times K$ matrix) such that
$\tilde{\pmb{G}} = \pmb{G}\mathcal{R}$
$\tilde{\pmb{F}} = \pmb{F}\mathcal{R}^{-1}$
and that
$\tilde{\pmb{H}}$ satisfies those properties?
Otherwise, what other approach could be useful? As I am having troubles with this problem, I am not totally sure there is a straightforward way to solve it, and I would also accept that there is no solution, but at least I would like to understand why. Any suggestion is welcomed

$\pmb{H}^{OPT}$ has $TL$ independent parameters, unless there are some restrictions on it you haven't mentioned. To match it by linear operations, you will need $TL$ independent parameters to adjust. A general $K\times K$ matrix has $K^2$ parameters you can adjust. But a rotation matrix has to satisfy a set of $\binom{ K+1}2$ equations, so it has only $\binom K2$ independent parameters. A necessary condition (not necessarily sufficient) for your plan to work is $\binom K2 \ge TL$.

@PaulSinclair thank you, that is a very good point. Unfortunately the condition is not satisfied so I need more restrictions. I edited the question with the restrictions I would like to satisfy. I hope this  reduces considerably the complexity of the problem

An alternative approach is possible if $G$ and $F$ have left-inverses: $K \times L$ and $K \times T$ matrices $G'$ and $F'$ such that $G'G = F'F = I_K$, the $K \times K$ identity matrix. Then you can just let $R = G'H^{OPT}F'^\intercal$. No guarantees it will a rotation matrix, though. $G$ and $F$ will have left inverses if and only if they are both rank $K$ (which also requires $T \ge K, L \ge K$).

such conditions are satisfied. What do you mean it is not guaranteed it will be a rotation matrix? I was trying to work out the condition $\tilde{\pmb{H}} = \pmb{H}$ but could not verify it. Notice I added more details to the problem at hand that should make it more clear

$\mathcal{R}^{-1}\pmb{F}$ makes no sense, as $\mathcal{R}^{-1}$ is K×K and $\pmb{F}$ is T×K. $\pmb{F}\mathcal{R}^{-1}$ would make sense.

true, I corrected that
